# sharepoint 2010 phone book without active directory

Tags: search, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, active-directory, metadata

I have an application that functions as a phone book in SharePoint 2010. This web application is external, built in JavaScript, and is used to search for users through active directory.

I would like to build this application in SharePoint altogether, by creating a Web Part, and search every SharePoint users instead of this external web application and AD. Does anyone have an idea or tips on what I should use to have this application in SharePoint?

It should be added that I would like the current function as today, custom fields as metadata (texboxes) to search within. Like country, city etc.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Not sure what you want to do. Either query against `SPWeb.AllUsers` or you want to add a new Authentication Provider to SharePoint?

Comment: The application is used to search for people in sharepoint, linked with an AD. I want to use this only in SharePoint to search for user profiles, instead of this external web application. I was thinking of building this code in a Web Part, because I want the similar functions.

Comment: most auth providers i have came to see lack detailed user informations, are the information you want to search for stored in sp? meaning, when you click on a user in sp, does is the form showing up properly filled?

Comment: The information is stored in SharePoint yes, via AD. When I search for e.g. name (Michael), everyone with the name Michael shows up, like a standard search engine.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should use [User Profiles](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee662538.aspx). You can configure User profile synchronization which will get data from AD for example.

Answer (score 0):

so if i understood your problem right, here is the answer to a similar (duplicate) question: [Getting members of an AD domain group using Sharepoint API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314767/getting-members-of-an-ad-domain-group-using-sharepoint-api)

please let me know if this did help you:) the problem you will see sooner or later is that SPWeb.AllUsers only knows Users which logged in at least once, you will fail to manually query Users which have never logged in unless you make SharePoint search the AD for you.